# Eclipse fails to auto-suggest Jackson class

Tags: eclipse, search, indexing, jackson, autosuggest

What is causing Eclipse to NOT recognize and consequently not offer any suggestion on an import of `JsonParser.Feature` as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Manually adding the static import of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES` (commented in the picture above), however, works fine.

[image]

Would it be the case that something is eclipsing the file on the classpath, and if so - what is Eclipse's strategy on resolving those conflicts?  Or is it something else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have exclude filters?

Comment: No, I didn't configure any filters, AFAIK.

Comment: Content assist is based on the project's _Java Build Path_ (make sure that none of the current 63 errors is a build error) whereas _Open Type_ shows types of _Java Build Paths_ of all(!) projects (and all installed JREs plus in PDE, types added to Java Search).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JsonParser class to access Feature since it is not a static member of the class. Instead you can directly use the Feature class :

```
mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 workarounds:

1. Use AutoComplete (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) to suggest classes:

[image]

2. Add `.` to class Name (`JsonParser.`) and then remove it (`JsonParser`) it will suggest all JsonParser classes:

[image]

Comment: That of course I did do and of course the way to make it work has long been found, my question is not about how to make it work but rather why Eclipse is not recognizing it one way (as I'm pointing out) and does recognize it the other way (as you are) - how does Eclipse performs this resolution internally and what prevents it from seeing both cases consistently and suggest a similar content assist in both instances.